# Image Processing: Noise Reduction using Vector Median Processing

Tags: java, image-processing

So, I have the task to create a Vector Median filter to help clean up noisy images. The logic behind this isn't too complex. First, just to level the paying field, all images are taken into java as 3d arrays of values. Red, Green, and Blue values are stored in a sort of row/column situation. so it works liks this when referencing pixel values:

```
[Color Component (Red, green, or blue)][Row][Col]
```

this will show you the exact pixel value at the specific spot of the image. I imagine an square when something that resembles the matrix when doing these.

So...to the filter..

From a scholarly article: "This filter performs non-linear filtering by moving a window [a mask] over a target pixel with RGB values and resets the value of that pixel to the pixel with the smallest sum of distance to the other pixels in the window."

If you haven't done any image processing work than this may seem somewhat confusing, but it's actually pretty straight forward. Your mask essentially is a box that moves through an image and creates a "neighborhood" of pixels the size of a predetermined constraint (I usually use a 3x3 "neighborhood", so I'll have 9 values -- Like in my code below.)

The gist is to choose a target pixel in neighborhood -- generally the center (and in this examples, ALWAYS the center) and calculate it's value based on the surrounding pixels. Pretty easy and it's also very impressive at eliminating noise in  images.

So the logic of creating the new pixel value is the most important part. Getting the "neighborhood" values is fairly easy and I will include that as well but the issue I am having is that I do not think I am calculating the logic correctly.. The logic, as stated above, compares each "neighborhood" pixel value to every other and creates a running sum of the distance for each pixel relative to the rest. The pixel whose running sum is LOWEST will become the new value of the target pixel.

The steps I follow (with code examples):

1. Get neighborhood values:

   ```
           //First two for loops will travel through column and row of image array. 
           //The third will travel through the RGB values (This is 4 values because Transparency is also accounted for here.)
           for (int row = 1; row < imageInDimension.getHeight() - 1; row++) {
           for (int column = 1; column < imageInDimension.getWidth() - 1; column++) {
           for (int ColComp = 1; ColComp < 4; ColComp++) {
           //////////////////////////
           //The Neighborhood////////
           //////////////////////////
           int pixelNeighbors[] = new int[9];
           //Assign values to neighborhood
           pixelNeighbors[0] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row - 1];
           pixelNeighbors[1] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row];
           pixelNeighbors[2] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row + 1];
           pixelNeighbors[3] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row - 1];
           pixelNeighbors[4] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row];
           pixelNeighbors[5] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row + 1];
           pixelNeighbors[6] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row - 1];
           pixelNeighbors[7] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row];
           pixelNeighbors[8] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row + 1];
   ```
2. Perform distance calculations on each pixel in the "neighborhood" relative to the other pixels in the "neighborhood" and store each value in a running sum (Using absolutes here because it is a distance formula)

   ```
               //Calculate distances
               for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                   runningSumPixel0 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[0] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel1 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[1] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel2 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[2] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel3 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[3] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel4 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[4] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel5 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[5] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel6 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[6] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel7 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[7] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                   runningSumPixel8 += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[8] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
               }
   ```
3. This is where I think I'm either making it too complicated or messing up the logic. I need to fund the lowest running sum and set the target pixel to that value. What I have now will compare each individual running sum to all values and verify if it is the lowest. If it is the lowest, it becomes the target pixel value. This is a very long one, I apologize.

   ```
                   //Determine lowest distance value and set target pixel to lowest distance value original value
                   if (runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel0 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to o position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[0];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel1 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 1 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[1];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel2 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 2 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[2];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel3 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 3 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[3];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel4 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 4 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[4];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel5 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 5 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[5];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel6 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 6 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[6];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel1 &
                           runningSumPixel7 < runningSumPixel8) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 7 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[7];

                   } else if (runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel0 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel2 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel3 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel4 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel5 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel6 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel7 &
                           runningSumPixel8 < runningSumPixel1) {
                       System.out.println("Target set to 8 position");
                       newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[8];

                   }
               }

           }
       }
   ```
4. Return new image.

I'm fairly certain my neighborhood is correct because I use the same algorithm to find the neighborhood on a different filter and it works flawlessly.

The problem: Essentially the code is not reducing the noise at all. In fact, it's doing NOTHING to the image. This makes no sense though because I am theoretically changing every pixel value..

Any advice? Hopefully this isn't to specific of a question. Thanks in advance!

ENTIRE METHOD AFTER SUGGESTED UPDATES:

```
protected Image VMFilter (Image imageIn) {
        //Get Image Dimensions
        Dimension imageInDimension = getImageDimension(imageIn);

        //calculate total number of pixels
        double totalPixels = imageInDimension.getHeight() * imageInDimension.getWidth();

        //Move image into an array.."old image"
        int OldImageTGRB[][][] = pixelsArrayToTRGBArray(imageToPixelsArray(imageIn), imageInDimension);
        //Create new image where new values will be stored
        int newImageTRGB[][][] = pixelsArrayToTRGBArray(imageToPixelsArray(imageIn), imageInDimension);


        //////////////////////////////////
        //////////THE LOGIC///////////////
        //////////////////////////////////
        //Sort through oldImage TRGB and create the neighborhood from values
        for (int row = 1; row < imageInDimension.getHeight() - 1; row++) {
            for (int column = 1; column < imageInDimension.getWidth() - 1; column++) {
                //Will Cycle through the color components assigning values to the neighborhood
                for (int ColComp = 1; ColComp < 4; ColComp++) {

                    //////////////////////////
                    //The Neighborhood////////
                    //////////////////////////
                    int pixelNeighbors[] = new int[9];

                    //Assign values to neighborhood
                    pixelNeighbors[0] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row - 1];
                    pixelNeighbors[1] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row];
                    pixelNeighbors[2] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column - 1][row + 1];
                    pixelNeighbors[3] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row - 1];
                    pixelNeighbors[4] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row];
                    pixelNeighbors[5] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column][row + 1];
                    pixelNeighbors[6] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row - 1];
                    pixelNeighbors[7] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row];
                    pixelNeighbors[8] = OldImageTGRB[ColComp][column + 1][row + 1];

                    //Create running sum variables to keep track of distance calculation sums
                    int runningSumPixels[] = new int[9];


                    //Calculate distances
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        runningSumPixels[i] += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[i] - pixelNeighbors[i]);
                    }

                    int iLow = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
                        if (runningSumPixels[i] < lowest) {
                            iLow = i;
                            lowest = runningSumPixels[i];
                        }
                        System.out.println("Old Value:" + newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row]);
                        newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[iLow];
                        System.out.println("New Value:" + newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        //Return new image..
        return pixelsArrayToImage(
                TRGBArrayToPixelsArray(newImageTRGB, imageInDimension), imageInDimension);
    }
```

Comment: **Warning!** the code above does not compute a vector median. This is an attempt at an expensive way of computing the median for each channel separately. A vector median requires using each pixel’s RGB value as a vector, and compute vector distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERROR:** in the Step 3 if-statements, Java logical AND operator is `&&`, not `&`.

**POSSIBLE ERROR:** in the Step 2 loop, seems to me that `i` should be allowed to take the value 8, changing the condition to `i < 9` instead of `i < 8`.

**IMPROVEMENT:** your current implementation of Step 3 is very naive (and probably faulty, because of the `<` instead of `<=` operators). Consider doing it this way:

- replace the 9 `runningSumPixel` variables with one array (like `pixelNeighbors`);
- replace Step 3 with the following code.

<sub><sup>CODE</sup></sub>

```
int iLow, lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    if (runningSumPixel[i] < lowest) {
        iLow = i;
        lowest = runningSumPixel[i];
}

newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row] = pixelNeighbors[iLow];
```

A bit smaller than what you had, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I converted your code for bitmap use-case.

```
protected Bitmap VMFilter (Bitmap bitmap) {
        //Get Image Dimensions
        //Dimension imageInDimension = getImageDimension(imageIn);

        //calculate total number of pixels
        double totalPixels = bitmap.getWidth()* bitmap.getHeight(); //imageInDimension.getHeight() * imageInDimension.getWidth();
        int w = bitmap.getWidth(),h = bitmap.getHeight();

        //Move image into an array.."old image"
        int OldImageTGRB[][][] = bitmapToTRGBArray(bitmap);
        //Create new image where new values will be stored
        int[][][] newImageTRGB = new int[w][h][3];////pixelsArrayToTRGBArray(bitmap);


        //////////////////////////////////
        //////////THE LOGIC///////////////
        //////////////////////////////////
        //Sort through oldImage TRGB and create the neighborhood from values
        int nearbyWindow = 10;
        for (int row = nearbyWindow; row < bitmap.getWidth() -nearbyWindow ; row++) {
            for (int column = nearbyWindow; column < bitmap.getHeight()-nearbyWindow ; column++) {
                //Will Cycle through the color components assigning values to the neighborhood
                for (int ColComp = 0; ColComp < 3; ColComp++) {

                    //////////////////////////
                    //The Neighborhood////////
                    //////////////////////////
                    int totalNeighbors = nearbyWindow * nearbyWindow;

                    int pixelNeighbors[] = new int[totalNeighbors];

                    
                    for(int i=0;i<totalNeighbors;i++){
                        pixelNeighbors[i] = OldImageTGRB[row-1][column-1][ColComp];
                    }

                    //Create running sum variables to keep track of distance calculation sums
                    int runningSumPixels[] = new int[totalNeighbors];


                    //Calculate distances
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalNeighbors; i++) {
                        runningSumPixels[i] += Math.abs(pixelNeighbors[i] - pixelNeighbors[ColComp]);
                    }

                    int iLow = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalNeighbors; ++i) {
                        if (runningSumPixels[i] < lowest) {
                            iLow = i;
                            lowest = runningSumPixels[i];
                        }
                        //System.out.println("Old Value:" + newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row]);
                        newImageTRGB[row][column][ColComp] = pixelNeighbors[iLow];
                        //System.out.println("New Value:" + newImageTRGB[ColComp][column][row]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Return new image..
        return pixelsArrayToBitmap(newImageTRGB, w,h, bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Note that OP’s code is incorrect and does not do a vector median: it does a per-channel computation, rather than using the RGB value as a vector and compute vector distances.